# PHP isn't receiving my AJAX POST data

Tags: php, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I'm building a single-page website using AngularJS, and I'm making a contact form. I have looked at a lot of q/a's on this topic, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have the basic HTML:

```
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <button class="submit">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
<!--Contact Form Ajax, added in HTML for MVP purposes, will be changed later-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var name = $('#name');
var email = $('#email');
var message = $('#message');

$('button.submit').click(function() {

    alert("Worked");
    var contact_data = {
        'sender_name': $(name).val(),
        'sender_email': $(email).val(),
        'sender_message': $(message).val()
    };
        console.log(contact_data);
        $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/php/contact.php',
        data: contact_data
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert('Success!');
        console.log('Submitted succesfully:' + data);

    }).fail(function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Failed :(');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

My PHP (located in a separate file):

```
<?php

$name = isset($_POST['sender_name']) ? $_POST['sender_name'] : '';

echo $name;

?>
```

I didn't include the php file in my main view, but I am checking out the results of the echo by looking at localhost:7070/php/contact.php (Figured if my PHP is just running backend to send an email, I don't need to include it in the view). All I see when I look at the echo is blank space, and if I remove the isset logic, I get an "unidentified index" error for 'sender_name'. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST);` in your `php` file and inspect the response in the developer console.

Comment: Why is that tagged Angularjs?

Comment: @JohannesJander it's an AngularJS app, I've reached the point where I'm telling as much as I can to help diagnose the problem

Comment: @AlexAndrei when I do that all I get is: Array()

Comment: Just wondering why one would use everything except Angular in an Angular app to read the form fields and POST them.

Comment: @JohannesJander I'm fairly new to Angular, wasn't aware I could use Angular to read the form fields and POST (I have some experience with AJAX). Do you have a recommended tutorial for reading and posting form data via Angular?

Comment: [Here is one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way) that is pretty close to yours, using jQuery & PHP. They show how to move it to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing ''

FROM:

```
var contact_data = {
    'sender_name': $(name).val(),
    'sender_email': $(email).val(),
    'sender_message': $(message).val()
};
```

TO:

```
var contact_data = {
    sender_name: $(name).val(),
    sender_email: $(email).val(),
    sender_message: $(message).val()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('#message').val();  


var contact_data = {
     'sender_name': name,
     'sender_email': email,
     'sender_message': message
 };
```

Comment: I tried using all of these methods, but it's still not working. I know my POST is being submitted in an array format like expected, but after doing print_r($_POST) in my php file, I saw that the PHP file is only receiving an empty array (it prints out Array()). Could it be in the format of the data I'm sending?

Comment: if you can get your data in console. log(contact_data)  then your format is also ok.  other code looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

jsut change the  `method:'POST'` to `type = 'POST'` inside **ajax** function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var name = $('#name');
var email = $('#email');
var message = $('#message');

$('button.submit').click(function() {

    alert("Worked");
    var contact_data = {
        'sender_name': $(name).val(),
        'sender_email': $(email).val(),
        'sender_message': $(message).val()
    };
        console.log(contact_data);
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/php/contact.php',
        data: contact_data
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert('Success!');
        console.log('Submitted succesfully:' + data);

    }).fail(function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Failed :(');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow format, I hope it will help you

```
var contact_data = {
    'sender_name': $(name).val(),
    'sender_email': $(email).val(),
    'sender_message': $(message).val()
};

console.log(contact_data);

$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/php/contact.php',
    data: {contact_data: contact_data},
}).done(function(data) {
    alert('Success!');
    console.log('Submitted succesfully:' + data);
}).fail(function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert('Failed :(');
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you are getting value after this. Then the function is not sending value by defining a variable

```
$('button.submit').click(function() {

    alert("Worked");
 //   var contact_data = {
 //       'sender_name': $(name).val(),
        'sender_email': $(email).val(),
 //       'sender_message': $(message).val()
  //  };
        console.log(contact_data);
        $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/php/contact.php',
        data: {
        'sender_name': $(name).val(),
        'sender_email': $(email).val(),
        'sender_message': $(message).val()
    }
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert('Success!');
        console.log('Submitted succesfully:' + data);

    }).fail(function(textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Failed :(');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });
});
});
```